# I've some results in Number Theory, but I don't know if they're already discovered, what should I do with them?

Tags: number-theory

I checked the net but didn't find anything similar.

1. If $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is divisible by $k$ but not $k^2$, $x^n+y^n+z^n$ is divisible by $k$. $n$ belongs to natural numbers, $k$ can only be $2$ or $3$.
2. $10, 11, 12$ and $13$ are the only four consecutive numbers, whose square will be same if you flip both the number and the square. Like $10^2=100$,$11^2=121$, $12^2=144$ , $21^2=441$, $13^2=169$, $31^2=961$.
3. In $a^n+b^n=c^n$ ,$a<b<c$, if $n\ge b/2$ then $c$ will always lie between $(b,b+1)$.

Comment: You could maybe start off by showing what you found first ^^

Comment: Best would be to read some books on number theory, rather than relying on what can be found online.

Comment: @lulu this is one of them. If x^3+y^3+z^3 is divisible by k but not k^2, x^n+y^n+z^n is divisible by k. n belongs to natural numbers, k can be 2 or 3

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I just wanted to tell him that he needs to give more details. He wants help and just says, I found something. If he really discovered something new. He can post it here and directly get a affirmation that he was the first person to publicly state the theorem.

Comment: @AshishGoel  I don't understand.  Your comment does not include any links or details.

Comment: @ Ashish Goel: Write it down, you can show us your results for verification. If correct and somewhat interesting you can publish a paper. This thread can serve as evidence that you found these results should someone try to steal your work. Also there is nothing in your previous comment.

Comment: @lulu check my comment.

Comment: @AshishGoel Show us all your results don't be shy ^^

Comment: Ok.  As to $k=2$...the only way that sum can be even is if all three terms are even, or if exactly one of the terms is even.  In either case, your claim is obvious.  Claims of this type are often pretty straight forward exercises in modular arithmetic.

Comment: Number 2 is also true for 100,101,102,103. also for 1000,1001,1002, 1003 and so on. So they are not the only ones.

Comment: @themaker Isn't it obvious? You're just adding 0 between 10,11,12,13. Can you find any other Numbers?

Comment: @Ashish Goel yea, it's obvious. Maybe you and I have different definitions of the word 'only'.

Comment: @themaker what about other two?

Comment: @MorganRodgers what method did you use to prove no. 3 ?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I did, but I thought you must have checked if it's true or not if you never saw it before.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks. The proof I've for the last one is very complicated. What method would you use for proving it? I proved it using geometry. Can you suggest any other method?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Sorry if I didn't clarify, it's only valid for positive integers.

Comment: @MorganRodgers only a,b and n are positive integers.